# Sliding Tab Layout Not Working for API 15

Tags: java, android, tabbar, horizontalscrollview

Has anyone attempted to use the SlidingTabLayout provided by Google with API 15? For some reason, when working with it on API 15, the tab bar does not slide at all.

```
 public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView
```

From what I can tell HorizontalScrollView should work with API 15. It works with API 16. Keep in mind this is on an emulator. This really is not a code related question. I want to know if anyone else has tried this and experienced a similar issue.

[image: TabBar]

Comment: You should be using [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), part of the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) instead

Comment: Got it working thanks